# How to add an item to an arrayList in Kotlin only at specific positions?

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to add values to an arrayList only at specific positions. For example, if the value exists for position 0, then add it to array, else skip and get to next position and check the condition again. Is this possible? I tried something but I'm getting this error: **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0**

**My code:**

```
for(item in reverseTicketsList){
        if(i<=6) {
            val value: String = item.total!!.replaceFirst(",", ".")
            val date: String = item.label!!.replace(".2020", "")
            var j = 0
            if (value.toFloat() != 0F) {
                if (item.values.first!!.toFloat() != 0F) {
                    hoursValuesArray.add(j, item.values.first!!.toFloat())
                    j++
                }

                else{
                   j++
                }
                if (item.values.second!!.toFloat() != 0F) {
                    hoursValuesArray.add(j, item.values.second!!.toFloat())
                    j++
                }
                else{
                    j++
                }
                if (item.values.third!!.toFloat() != 0F) {
                    hoursValuesArray.add(j, item.values.third!!.toFloat())
                    j++
                }
                else{
                   j++
                }
                entriesVerticalBar.add(BarEntry(i, hoursValuesArray.toFloatArray()))
                barLabesArrayList.add(date)
                i++
                hoursValuesArray.clear()
            }
        }
```

If you have any solutions please let me know! Thanks

**EDIT**
A simpler example of what I'm trying to do and what I need:

```
val exampleArray: MutableList<Float> = ArrayList()
    exampleArray.add(0, 10f)
    exampleArray.add(2, 10f)
    exampleArray.add(4, 10f)
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: What should I add to question? @Sweeper

Comment: A minimal piece of code that I can copy and paste into my IDE and run and see the error "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0"

Comment: I edited the question and added a simpler version of code of what I need. thanks @Sweeper

Comment: So if you add an item at index 2 when the list has only 1 element, what do you expect the element at index 1 to be?

Comment: I dont want to be any element at index 1, that's what I'm asking. is it possible?

Comment: Let me change how I ask: what do you expect `exampleArray[1]` to give you?

Comment: I'm trying to create a stacked barChart with 3 intervals, and if I have no values at interval 2 for example, I don't want to have any value there. That's why I need an array with values only at specific indexes. So I expect a null value there or something..

Comment: How about putting 0s (instead of null) there?

Comment: I tried but then on the bottom of the chart are shown those 0s and it's not looking good..

Comment: Then your chart-drawing code is relevant. This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: should I add my chart code to the question? Could you please review it?

Comment: You could instead of using arrays maybe use a better data structure that reflects your case, namely a sorted map: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-map-of.html